# What is the difference between %p and 0x%08x

Tags: c

the question says it all.
In c, when trying to get the address of a pointer or something, I know the commands:

```
%p
```

and

```
0x%08x
```

I know that they both return addresses, but why use one over another?

Check this out:

```
int main () {

int i[1] = {1};
int *int_pointer;

int_pointer = i;

printf("0x%08x\n",&i);
printf("0x%08x\n", int_pointer);

printf("%p\n",&i);
printf("%p\n", int_pointer);

}
```

This code yields this response:
    0x60506b00
    0x60506b00
    0x7ffe60506b00
    0x7ffe60506b00

if both refer to the addresses, then how come they are different depending on if you use %p or 0x%08x?

Which is the actual address?

Comment: Your pointers are 64 bit, and `%08x` only prints 32 bits of hex.

Answer (score 12):

`printf("%p", p)` expects a `void*` pointer as argument.  `printf("0x%08x", n)` expects an `unsigned int` as argument.

Passing a pointer to the latter might work anyway provided that an `unsigned int` and a pointer are "similar enough" in their representations on the stack.  But to be safe and correct no matter what your machine is, always use `"%p"` with pointers.

Comment: so if i was using a char, I would just convert it into an int. Correct me if im wrong

Comment: i edited my original post to reflect an example of the usage and i'm still confused. do you mind clarifying it?

Comment: @yasgur99: it appears that pointers are 64-bits wide on your machine, but the `%08x` conversion specifier only prints the low-order 32 bits.  Pointers are not unsigned integers, and they don't have to have the same size or representation as unsigned integers.  *Always* use `%p` to print pointer values, at least if you want meaningful output.

Comment: so what should I use if I wanted to print the address of integers or other variables

Comment: @yasgur99: assuming you want to print the address of a variable named `a` (regardless of type), you would write `printf( "%p\n", (void *) &a );`

Answer (score 4):

Because `%p` is the portable way of doing it. Even though a pointer stores an address, it is not an integer (and the standard does not require a compiler to use integers for pointer representations), hence it is not appropriate to use an integer specifier.

Comment: what about when using a char

Comment: a `char` is implicitly convertible to an integer.